# Cooperative cancellation in F# with cancel continuation

Tags: asynchronous, f#, cancellation

*Probably I have here 2 questions instead of one, but anyway.*

I'm implementing cooperative cancellation as [here suggested](http://www.fssnip.net/gu). Here is my test code:

```
type Async with
    static member Isolate(f : CancellationToken -> Async<'T>) : Async<'T> =
        async {
            let! ct = Async.CancellationToken
            let isolatedTask = Async.StartAsTask(f ct)
            return! Async.AwaitTask isolatedTask
        }

let testLoop (ct: CancellationToken) = async {
    let rec next ix =
        if ct.IsCancellationRequested then ()
        else 
            printf "%i.." ix
            Thread.Sleep 10  
            next (ix+1)
    next 1
}

let cancellationSource = new CancellationTokenSource()
let onDone () = printfn "!! DONE"
let onError _ = printfn "!! ERROR"
let onCancel _ = printfn "!! CANCEL"

Async.StartWithContinuations (Async.Isolate testLoop, onDone, onError, onCancel, cancellationSource.Token)

Thread.Sleep(100)
cancellationSource.Cancel ()
Thread.Sleep(500)
```

As you can see, I start async with *done*, *cancel* and *error* continuations. If I run that code as is, I'll get the following output:

> 1..2..3..4..5..6..7..8..!! DONE

If I slightly update the `Isolate` method as follows:

```
    static member Isolate(f : CancellationToken -> Async<'T>) : Async<'T> =
        async {
            let! ct = Async.CancellationToken
            let isolatedTask = Async.StartAsTask(f ct)
            let! x = Async.AwaitTask isolatedTask
            x
        }
```

I get the expected (by myself) output:

> 1..2..3..4..5..6..7..!! CANCEL

Why do we have such difference in the behavior?

Is it possible to abort the `testLoop`, if it does not cancelled within some timeout?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `async` block checks for cancellation of the `Async.CancellationToken` only before and after bind (written using `let!`). This means that when the token gets cancelled, the workflow will only get cancelled when there is more work to be done.

It is also worth noting that `isolatedTask` does not itself gets cancelled in this example, because it just terminates regularly (using `if`).

In your case:

- When you use just `return!`, the task returns regularly, `Async.AwaitTask` returns regularly and nothing is done afterwards so the workflow completes.
- When you use `let!` followed by `return`, the task returns regularly and `Async.AwaitTask` returns regularly, but then `let!` checks for cancellation *before* running `return` and this cancels the workflow.