# F# CancellationTokenSource.Cancel() does not cancel the underlying work

Tags: asynchronous, f#

I have some potentially very long running function, which may sometimes hang up. So, I thought that if I wrap it into an `async` workflow, then I should be able to cancel it. Here is an FSI example that does not work (but the same behavior happens with the compiled code):

```
open System.Threading

let mutable counter = 0

/// Emulates an external C# sync function that hung up.
/// Please, don't change it to some F# async stuff because
/// that won't fix that C# method.
let run() =
    while true
        do
            printfn "counter = %A" counter
            Thread.Sleep 1000
            counter <- counter + 1


let onRunModel() =
    let c = new CancellationTokenSource()
    let m = async { do run() }
    Async.Start (m, c.Token)
    c


let tryCancel() =
    printfn "Starting..."
    let c = onRunModel()
    printfn "Waiting..."
    Thread.Sleep 5000
    printfn "Cancelling..."
    c.Cancel()
    printfn "Waiting again..."
    Thread.Sleep 5000
    printfn "Completed."


#time
tryCancel()
#time
```

If you run it in FSI, then you will see something like that:

```
Starting...
Waiting...
counter = 0
counter = 1
counter = 2
counter = 3
counter = 4
Cancelling...
Waiting again...
counter = 5
counter = 6
counter = 7
counter = 8
counter = 9
Completed.
Real: 00:00:10.004, CPU: 00:00:00.062, GC gen0: 0, gen1: 0, gen2: 0
counter = 10
counter = 11
counter = 12
counter = 13
counter = 14
counter = 15
counter = 16
```

which means that it does not stop at all after `c.Cancel()` is called.

What am I doing wrong and how to make such thing work?

Here is some additional information:

1. When the code hangs up, it does it in some external sync C# library,
   which I have no control of. So checking for cancellation token in
   the code that I control is useless. That's why function `run()`
   above was modeled that way.
2. I don't need any communication of completion and / or progress. It's already done via some messaging system and it is out of scope
   of the question.
3. Basically I just need to kill background work as soon as I "decide" to do so.

Comment: What do you mean by kill? `CanellationToken` is just a notification. If the method doesn't actually register itself or check for cancellation it doesn't actually do anything.

Comment: You're using Tread.Sleep. Try Async.Sleep. Not sure, but I suspect that will respect cancelling.

Comment: Exactly. I am trying to find an alternative, which will work. E.g. `t = new Thread(fun () -> run())` ... and then calling `t.Abort()` does terminate the thread but it does down with a bang in the FSI - the whole FSI session is terminated.

Comment: `Thread.Sleep` is there on purpose. Please, see comment #1 at the end of the question.

Comment: I don't think you should use thread stuff at all. Async and Task is not thread stuff, though they use threads to get their work done.

Comment: Ok, I get it. How about this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37596011/cooperative-cancellation-in-f-with-cancel-continuation

Comment: Same, but less code : http://www.fssnip.net/gu/title/Cooperative-cancellation-in-Async-workflows

Comment: No, it won't work. Function `run()` models C# method that hangs up. Once the code gets there, then it never returns. So any checks for requested cancellations are useless :( Some completely different approach seems to be needed.

Comment: `Thread.Abort` should never be called. It can leave your program in an undefined state.

Answer (score 1):

You are handing off control to a code segment, which, albeit wrapped in an `async` block, has no means of checking for the cancellation. Were you to construct your loop directly wrapped in an `async`, or have it replaced by a recursive `async` loop, it will work as expected:

```
let run0 () =   // does not cancel
    let counter = ref 0
    while true do
        printfn "(0) counter = %A" !counter
        Thread.Sleep 1000
        incr counter
let m = async { run0 () }

let run1 () =   // cancels
    let counter = ref 0
    async{
        while true do
            printfn "(1) counter = %A" !counter
            Thread.Sleep 1000
            incr counter }

let run2 =      // cancels too
    let rec aux counter = async {
        printfn "(2) counter = %A" counter
        Thread.Sleep 1000
        return! aux (counter + 1) }
    aux 0

printfn "Starting..."
let cts = new CancellationTokenSource()
Async.Start(m, cts.Token)
Async.Start(run1(), cts.Token)
Async.Start(run2, cts.Token)
printfn "Waiting..."
Thread.Sleep 5000
printfn "Cancelling..."
cts.Cancel()
printfn "Waiting again..."
Thread.Sleep 5000
printfn "Completed."
```

A word of caution though: Nested `async` calls in F# are automatically checked for cancellation, which is why `do! Async.Sleep` is preferable. If you are going down the recursive route, be sure to enable tail-recursion via `return!`. Further reading: Scott W.'s blog on [Asynchronous programming](https://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/posts/concurrency-async-and-parallel/), and [Async in C# and F# Asynchronous gotchas in C#](http://tomasp.net/blog/csharp-async-gotchas.aspx/) by Tomas Petricek.

Comment: The answer is great, but... please see additional information #1 in the question: _When the code hangs up, it does it in some external sync C# library, which I have no control of._ .So, `run()` was "designed" to mimic that behavior. If you could rewrite your code so that it could use the original `run()` while being able to cancel the computation, that would be great.

Answer (score -1):

This piece of code was developed to solve a situation where I couldn't get some calls to terminate/timeout. They would just hang. Maybe you can get some ideas that will help you solve your problem.

The interesting part for you would be only the two first functions. The rest is only to demonstrate how I'm using them.

```
module RobustTcp =

    open System
    open System.Text
    open System.Net.Sockets
    open Railway

    let private asyncSleep (sleepTime: int) (error: 'a) = async {
        do! Async.Sleep sleepTime
        return Some error
    }

    let private asyncWithTimeout asy (timeout: int) (error: 'a) =
        Async.Choice [ asy; asyncSleep timeout error ]

    let private connectTcpClient (host: string) (port: int) (tcpClient: TcpClient) = async {
        let asyncConnect = async {
            do! tcpClient.ConnectAsync(host, port) |> Async.AwaitTask
            return Some tcpClient.Connected }
        match! asyncWithTimeout asyncConnect 1_000 false with
        | Some isConnected -> return Ok isConnected
        | None -> return Error "unexpected logic error in connectTcpClient"
        }

    let private writeTcpClient (outBytes: byte[]) (tcpClient: TcpClient) = async {
        let asyncWrite = async {
            let stream = tcpClient.GetStream()
            do! stream.WriteAsync(outBytes, 0, outBytes.Length) |> Async.AwaitTask
            do! stream.FlushAsync() |> Async.AwaitTask
            return Some (Ok ()) }
        match! asyncWithTimeout asyncWrite 10_000 (Error "timeout writing") with
        | Some isWrite -> return isWrite
        | None -> return Error "unexpected logic error in writeTcpClient"
        }

    let private readTcpClient (tcpClient: TcpClient) = async {
        let asyncRead = async {
            let inBytes: byte[] = Array.zeroCreate 1024
            let stream = tcpClient.GetStream()
            let! byteCount = stream.ReadAsync(inBytes, 0, inBytes.Length) |> Async.AwaitTask
            let bytesToReturn = inBytes.[ 0 .. byteCount - 1 ]
            return Some (Ok bytesToReturn) }
        match! asyncWithTimeout asyncRead 2_000 (Error "timeout reading reply") with
        | Some isRead ->
            match isRead with
            | Ok s -> return Ok s
            | Error error -> return Error error
        | None -> return Error "unexpected logic error in readTcpClient"
        }

    let sendReceiveBytes (host: string) (port: int) (bytesToSend: byte[]) = async {
        try
            use tcpClient = new TcpClient()
            match! connectTcpClient host port tcpClient with
            | Ok isConnected ->
                match isConnected with
                | true ->
                    match! writeTcpClient bytesToSend tcpClient with
                    | Ok () ->
                        let! gotData = readTcpClient tcpClient
                        match gotData with
                        | Ok result -> return Ok result
                        | Error error -> return Error error
                    | Error error -> return Error error
                | false -> return Error "Not connected."
            | Error error -> return Error error
        with
        | :? AggregateException as ex ->
            (* TODO ? *)
            return Error ex.Message
        | ex ->
            (*
            printfn "Exception in getStatus : %s" ex.Message
            *)
            return Error ex.Message
    }

    let sendReceiveText (host: string) (port: int) (textToSend: string) (encoding: Encoding) =
        encoding.GetBytes textToSend
        |> sendReceiveBytes host port
        |> Async.map (Result.map encoding.GetString)
```

Comment: The idea here is that asyncSleep will timeout, and then so will asyncWithTimeout, so that even if the TCP stuff won't timeout, there will be a timeout.

Comment: Perhaps somebody will tell me that the TCP stuff does have timeouts that I could have used. My problem is that there are situations when those timeouts wont work, and calls will hang anyway. Which is why this was the only completely foolproof way I could find in order to always guarantee there would be no hang, whatever problem might surface.